# How to access passed parameter in modalPanel

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have a requirement in which on click of the image I need to display the bigger size of the same image on the modal panel.

For this what I did was to pass the image location as a f:param to the modal panel and then use the passed parameter in image tag.

But somehow I am not able to get the value of parameter I pass.

Here is the code :

This is how I activate the modalPanel and how I pass the parameter usingf:param

```
<h:graphicImage value="../images/DSCN0965.JPG" height="50" width="50" styleClass="iconClass">

     <rich:componentControl for="imagePanel" operation="show" event="onclick">

         <f:param value="../images/DSCN0965.JPG" name="imagePath"/>

     </rich:componentControl>

 </h:graphicImage>
```

This is modal panel code and how I try to get the f:param value here...

```
<rich:modalPanel id="imagePanel" width="600" height="600">

      <f:facet name="header">

          <h:panelGroup>

              <h:outputText value="Image"></h:outputText>

          </h:panelGroup>

      </f:facet>

      <f:facet name="controls">

          <h:panelGroup>

              <h:graphicImage value="../images/closeIcon.GIF" styleClass="iconClass" id="closeImageLink"/>

              <rich:componentControl for="imagePanel" attachTo="closeImageLink" operation="hide" event="onclick"/>

          </h:panelGroup>

      </f:facet>

      <h:outputLabel value="#{imagePath}"/>

      <h:graphicImage value="{imagePath}" height="400" width="500" styleClass="iconClass"/>

  </rich:modalPanel>
```

Can you give me idea as to how to access the passed parameter value?

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are not required to set the param value for displaying a larger image instead this can be easily accomplished just using `javascript`.

Give the image element in model panel `id` say "largeImage" and use the following script in your page smaller image

`onclick = "document.getElementById('largeImage').src = this.src;"`

following the script to open the panel.

For passing param value, you need to bind it to JSF backing bean object as described [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html).

Comment: Thats right, I had already accomplished it using the javascript. I do not have to use f:param for this purpose